# Creating a powershell script to unlock AD accounts

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to Powershell, I am trying to create a fast script that I can run as admin with one click of a button to display the current accounts locked out first and then have a pre written text in the command line, in which I can just type the SAM account name I want to unlock, since I don't want to unlock them all at once necessarily.

My question is, how can I get PS to run a command and then pre write text into command line for the to fill the rest in and execute?

```
Search-ADAccount -lockedout | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName
Unlock-ADAccount -Identity samAccountName
```

Answer (score 0):

Read-host is one option when working interactively.

e.g.

```
Search-ADAccount -lockedout | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName

$samAccountName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the samAccountName of the account you wish to unlock'

if($samAccountName) {
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $samAccountName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to prompt a text for the users to be unlocked, you can use the `read-host` command:

and you can unlock multiple accounts at once as follow:

```
Search-ADAccount -lockedout | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName
$Samaccountnames = Read-Host "Enter SamAccountNames of accounts to unlock separated by comma ','"
$Samaccountnames =$Samaccountnames.split(",")
$Samaccountnames | % {Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

this command will unlock all AD users in a domain.

if you want o add confirnation add -Confirm

```
Search-ADAccount -Lockedout | Unlock-AdAccount -Confirm
```

if not:

```
Search-ADAccount -Lockedout | Unlock-AdAccount
```

this command will final all locked user account:

```
Search-ADAccount -lockedout | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName
```